# Catching exceptions in else

Tags: python, testing, exception

Is this a good pythonic way to test something for equality, and catch exceptions in else?

```py
try:
    # Check for equality
    debug.assert_eq(data, None)
    debug.assert_eq(id, None)
    debug.assert_eq(time, None)
    debug.assert_eq(group, None)

except Exception:
    print("OK")

else:
    raise Exception('None found')
```

Comment: why don't you flip your logic and check for not equals instead?

Comment: well that make sense

Comment: What is the test supposed to achieve? That *at most one* of those 4 values is not `None`? Or that *at least one* is not `None`? Why not just *count the `None` values*?

Comment: No.  You can't actually "test something for equality" - you need TWO things so that one can be equal to the other one.  A good Pythonic way is to use the == operator.  If you're checking to see if a variable is None, use the `is` operator: `if x is None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is rather.. involved. If you want to test if *at least one* of those variables is not `None`, then use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
debug.assert(any(v is not None for v in (data, id, time, group)))
```

`any()` iterates over the `v is not None for v in (data, id, time, group)` generator expression and returns `True` the moment it encounters a `True` result. This means that if `data` is not `None`, then the other 3 values are not tested. If, however, all 4 values are `None` then `any()` returns `False` and the assertion test fails.

I don't know what framework you are using to test assertions, I assumed there would be a `.assert()` method.

When catching an assertion failure exception, I would *not* catch `Exception`, that's way too broad and will mask bugs. A test framework will raise specific exceptions to signal assertion failure, such as the built in [`AssertionError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#AssertionError). Catch that specific exception instead, if you must.